# How to host data in common server so that it can be accessed by android applications

Tags: android, hosting

I am creating an android app, Where the all installed app has to retrieve data from a common place(server). certainly I am not trying for web hosting. Please let me know how to achieve it.

Regards,
Prem

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to buy your own server and you dont want to do server side code then best choice is Firebase, That was best idea for store data into NoSql way data and also option to store file using google Bucket. I think this was best idea.